# Removing double quotes from Json String Key

Tags: java, json, string, java-8

The string in java like below
{"a":"hello","b":["r","s"],"j":10}

I want output as:
{a:"hello",b:["r","s"],j:10}

Remove Quotes from key of json string

Use java language for solution

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question: why would you like to do that? While the first one is valid json, the second one is not. I don't think it's worth to sacrfifice interoperability for that.

Comment: for your reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996325/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-json-string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but here comes a simple way if you are using `Jackson` as your `JSON` library.

**Code snippet**

```
String jsonStr = "{\"a\":\"hello\",\"b\":[\"r\",\"s\"],\"j\":10}";
     
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class)));
```

> NOTE: `JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES` is deprecated since `2.10`.

**Console output**

```
{a:"hello",b:["r","s"],j:10}
```

Comment: @Vedant Mehra Please let me know if my solution works for you, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand why would you want to do that, because post such manipulation your JSON will not qualify as a JSON. Assuming it's a string, I found a tricky way to do this. Iterate over JSON recursively and append a token before and after a key. Use replaceAll to remove all instances of token with ".

Example if your JSON is like this:

```
{
 "key1": {
   "key2": ["aaaa", "bbbb"]
 }
}
```

You would convert it to this form:

```
{
 "$$$$_key1_$$$$": {
   "$$$$_key2_$$$$": ["aaaa", "bbbb"]
 }
}
```

Then, post stringification, you can replace all instances of `\"$$$$_` and `_$$$$\"` with empty char.

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("sample_json.json")));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String str = change(jsonObject).toString();

        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\"\\$\\$\\$\\$_", "")
                .replaceAll("_\\$\\$\\$\\$\"", "")
        );

    }


    public static JSONObject change(JSONObject jsonObject){
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        Map<String, Object> map = jsonObject.toMap();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
            Object object = entry.getValue();
            if (object instanceof JSONObject){
                result.put(appendToken(entry.getKey()), change((JSONObject) object));
            } else if (object instanceof JSONArray){
                JSONArray objArray = (JSONArray) object;
                JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray();
                for (Object arrObj : objArray){
                    if (arrObj instanceof JSONObject){
                        resultArray.put(change((JSONObject) arrObj));
                    } else {
                        resultArray.put(arrObj);
                    }
                }
                result.put(appendToken(entry.getKey()), resultArray);
            } else {
                result.put(appendToken(entry.getKey()), object);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String appendToken(String key){
        return "$$$$_" + key + "_$$$$";
    }
```